# .save() not working inside callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently using the "request" module to get data from an external page:
if i use the following code, it doesn't work:

```
request(SITE_URL, function (error, response, body) {
    var user = new gasStation({ id: 12345, name: 'Gustavo' });
    user.save();
});
```

But if i make the call outside the request function it works as expected:

```
var user = new gasStation({ id: 12345, name: 'Gustavo' });
user.save();
request(SITE_URL, function (error, response, body) {
  // some stuff
});
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: How do you check whether it worked or not?

Comment: General suggestion. Never ignore the `error` parameter.

Comment: Could you specify how exactly the first piece of code `doesn't work`?

Answer (score 0):

First never ignore your error handler's. Check if error is true. Also your URL might be malformed check that. Lastly make sure the mongoose model for user is initialized. I only saw initialization outside the request.